# trouble compiling source code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I am porting some code from Gcc to visual c 6 but i got some error while compiling this code

```
XMLNode::XMLNode( const string & _name, const string & _value ) :
    XMLAbstractNode::XMLAbstractNode( _name, xml_node ),
    value( _value )
{// No code here.
}
```

it compiles on mingw gcc code blocks but get follwing error when compiling on visual c 
 6 it gives follwing error

```
error C2436 member function or nested class in constructor initializer list
```

what is meaning of abobe code as begiiner to c++ XMLNODE is drived class calling parent class constructor XMLABSTRACTNode with parameters .but wht is , value(_value) here how to compile code on vc6

Answer (score 0):

I think VC 6 complains about the initialization of the super class. Try the following code (replace the doubled class name `XMLAbstractNode::XMLAbstractNode` with just `XMLAbstractNode`):

```
XMLNode::XMLNode( const string & _name, const string & _value ) :
    XMLAbstractNode( _name, xml_node ),
    value( _value )
{
    // No code here.
}
```

The code `value(_value)` just initializes the member variable `value` with the passed string `_value`.